# Array Manipulation R

Tags: r

Apologies if this is the wrong title, I couldn't think what else to call it.

In matlab I was able to do the following:

```
x = (2,7,8)
var1 = (1:1:10,1)
var2 = var1(x,1)
```

Therefore it would create a new array. containing the values 2,7 and 8.

I am trying to replicate this process in R but I am struggling profusely and can't think how to word the question properly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I am trying to create a new array, **var2** by doing the following:

```
x = (2,7,8)

var1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

In matlab I could type the following:

```
var2 = var1(x,1)
```

Thus:

```
var2 = (2,7,8)
```

I am looking how to do this in R, using a defined variable to find the corresponding row numbers basically..

Comment: Also add expected result

Comment: What does `var1(x,1)` do in matlab ?

Comment: In matlab  `var1(x,1)` will make a new array for me with those variables in the defined `x`.

Comment: It's still not clear to me but I think by `using a defined variable to find the corresponding row numbers` you may need `match(x, var1)` which returns matches of positions of first argument in second.

Comment: Hmmm, let me see if I can explain one more time.
`var1 = 1 - 10` as described. `x=2,7,8`. I think in R it will go something like this:
`var2 = var1(x,1)` resulting in `var2 = ([2,7,8],1)`. Thus taking only those row numbers as defined by the `x` variable. 
As I said, i was not really sure how to ask the question correctly. I hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, if I corretly understand the problem, try to use this code:

```
x = c(2,7,8)
var1 = c(1:1:10,1)
var2 = var1[var1 %in% x]
var2
[1] 2 7 8
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this finds the row location of the numbers defined by x?

Comment: Is the match between the values in var1 and x, what are you looking for?

Comment: I am to blame. I was just wondering how to make `var2` in a similar way. I have an array exponentially larger, and I am trying to take the readings at the rows as defined by your `var2` solution.

Comment: Why not var2<-x?

Comment: Because in my larger array, I have 30K + of specific rows I would like to extract so I need:
`var2 <- var1(x,1)`

Comment: I was hoping the solution above would allow me to do the following: 
I have four variables in a data frame`Df = data.frame(var1 var2 var3 var4)` they are all the same length and 1 column, we shall say the dims are 30,000 (rows) x 1 (column). 
I have found the locations of my errors with this code:
`ErLoc1 = which(Var2 %in% Error)` 
This gives me the row numbers where the errors occur i.e. the location. I then want to apply this to `Df` So then I have `Df2` which will only be formed of the rows indicated from `ErLoc1`. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Please, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and improve your question with the above details and other details needed.

Comment: I was just stating what the solution to the above question would enable me to do. In Matlab I believe it would.